# Trying to change page content by menu clicks

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, web

I'm trying to dynamically change the contents in my page, such that on a default page I can dynamically change the contents by clicking the menu options.
This seems entirely complicated to me.
Do I use the ONCLICK method, or other JavaScript functions or maybe PHP?

[This is how this simple website looks like and what I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bea11.png)

EDIT:

This is what I have done so far:

- I have a File with CSS working correctly
- I coded a MAIN_PAGE (index):

```html
<DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="pt-BR">

<html>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Controle_de_estoque.css">

</head>

<!--Site de Controle de Estoque em HMTL
    HOME-->


<title> Controle de Estoque</title>  <!--Título do Site-->


<body>


<div class="container">


<?php
include  ("path to header")

?>

<?php

include  ("path to a HOMEPAGE_DEFAULT file")

?>


</body>

</html>
```

So now I am trying to change the content of the page when clicking on one of the MENU options (nav).

```html
<header>


   CONTROLE DE ESTOQUE

   <img class="imgheader" src="Fotos/Estoque_header.jpg" style="max-width: 70%;height: auto">
</header>

    <nav>
    <a title="Página Inicial" href="index.php"><img src="Fotos/Home.png" style="max-width: 30px;float:center"></a>
    <a title="Estoque" href="paginas/Estoque.html">Estoque</a>
    <a title="Relatórios" href="index.php">Relatórios</a>
    <a title="Configurações" href="index.php">Configurações</a>
    <a title="Acesso Interno" href="index.php">Acessos Internos</a>
    </nav>
```

```html
<div>
<!--HOME-->
<article>
  <h1> Controle de Estoque </h1>
  <p> Escolha um dos itens no MENU acima para iniciar</p>
  <img class="imgArticle" src="Fotos/Integracao_tecnologia.jpg" style="max-width:40%,height: auto;width: 40% " alt="Integracao_tecnologia" title="Integracao_tecnologia">
</article>
<div>
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and make sure to take a [tour]

Comment: simplest version: use a `<a href="secondpage.php">Configura..</a>`

Comment: It all depends... You can PHP (`include` header, footer) and page refresh or load content dynamically using AJAX...

Comment: Can you add what you have done so far...

Comment: Roko C. Buljan, I am looking at AJAX at w3school, but all the examples show those javascript buttons, and i want it to change when clicking a CSS made button. I don't know if I just lack knowledge and logic, but I am very new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In using php you can seperate your contents into files and include them selectively using if...else,include('fileName.php') and checking for button click using isset('variableName') pls note that the code below have not been tested :

```
    vars.php
    <?php

    $color = 'green';
    $fruit = 'apple';

    ?>

    test.php

    <form name="new user" method="post" action=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?> > 

    <input type="submit"  value="show"/>
    </form>
    <?php

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
include 'vars.php';    
 echo "A $color $fruit";
}else{  
    //code goes here
}

    ?>
```

Edit in light of your comment:

```
<ul>
                <li><a href="?link=1" name="link1">link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="?link=2" name="link2">link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="?link=3" name="link3">link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="?link=4" name="link4">link 4</a></li>    
            </ul>

       <div id="mainSection">
            <?php
        $link=$_GET['link'];
        if ($link == '1'){
             include 'page1.php';
        }
        if ($link == '2'){
            include 'page2.php';
        }
        if ($link == '3'){
            include 'page3.php';
        }
        if ($link == '4'){
            include 'page4.php';
        }
            ?>  
        </div>
```

Comment: I guess i understand that. So I should do that using a form method then it will get my other files to change the website? Can I do that assigning it  to one of my menus within **<nav><a> Example </a></nav>**?

Comment: Thanks! That will help me a lot. I'm not a programmer. I'm a civil engineering student trying to build solutions for myself, so this is really not my thing.